# Did Drona help Ekalavya after taking guru-dakshina?

Tags: guru, dronacharya

In Mahabharata, Drona asked for the thumb of Ekalavya as guru-dakshina.

After receiving it, did Drona gave any special vidya or any other help to Ekalavya?

Comment: The thumb was for having already received the education, not for upcoming benefits. The guru-dakshina is after the education unlike current times.